# Как захватить текст/src в ссылке/изображении соответственно и распечатать их через разделитель?

Tags: javascript

Как захватить `текст/src` в `ссылке/изображении` соответственно и вставить полученные значения через разделитель, создав новый div по шаблону `<div>текст~src</div>` и удалив старый код.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img1.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 1</a>
  </div>
    <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img2.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 2</a>
  </div>
    <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img3.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что значит распечатать? На принтере? Куда вставлять новый div?

Comment: @UModeL я про document.Write или что-то типа. Вставить рядом, создав под каждую связку ссылка + изображение <div>, поместив значение внутрь

Comment: То есть добавить после уже существующего кода? Или вместо него?

Comment: @UModeL да, верно. Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @UModeL лучше вместо него. Старый код удалить

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let aItem = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
aItem.forEach(el => {
  let sHtml = `${el.querySelector('.link').textContent}~${el.querySelector('.img').src}`;
  el.innerHTML = sHtml;
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img1.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img2.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img3.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если нужно именно значение атрибута, а не полный путь к изображению:

```js
let aItem = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
aItem.forEach(el => {
  let sHtml = `${el.querySelector('.link').textContent}~${el.querySelector('.img').getAttribute('src')}`;
  el.innerHTML = sHtml;
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img1.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img2.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/img3.png" class="img">
    <a class="link">Текст 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```